# The connotation of "boob" and "tit"

Tags: connotation

The Americans coined 'boob' and left it to the British, I think, then now prefer 'tits', I think

Can you tell me which one is more acceptable in polite context or if they are equivalent, what is their connotation? Do you consider them vulgar? When I was in England boob seem to be an acceptable word

Comment: Neither one should be used in polite company if you are using them to refer to breasts. You can call someone a “boob” to mean “fool” or “bumbler” though. If you want to refer to breasts in a polite context, say *breasts*.

Comment: @DanBron, are they exactly on the same level on both sides of the ocean?

Comment: There aren’t really well-established “levels” as you suggest. Both are relatively crude but innocuous ways to refer to breasts. Something 11 year old boys would say to try to attract attention. I can’t speak for the Brits, all my comments apply to American English (though I do believe it’s the same for the Brits).

Comment: American here: I've heard both *boob* and *tit*, as well as many other colorful references. Usually not something I'd say in polite company. Generally, talking about sexual areas in polite company and outside of a health context would be gauche, so I'd stick to clear terms used in medicine, like *breast*.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin, can you suggest a  reference colorful yet more polite than boob?

Comment: Chartreuse breast. (Less jokingly, I'll spend a minute thinking, but the issue isn't just the term, but the subject - there are only a narrow set of topics for which it is appropriate to refer to lady bits or gentleman bits in polite conversation (i.e., people you may not know well or only know professionally, through church, and so on), and most slang terms don't fit that.)

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin, the link was very helpful, it seems to corroborate my view that 'boob' is by far more acceptable

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: If that's your conclusion, read closer: "

The usage to associate tits with boobs however, is purely sexist. In polite society you should mention neither, referring instead to the bosom that @Robusto mentions, or breast, but only when you must. "

Comment: Breast-feeding is a lovely/affectionate  use; showing a sublime relationship.  I don't think 'breast' can be replaced with either boobs or tits, here.

Comment: In America, "tits" was one of George Carlin's ["7 words you can't say on TV"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_dirty_words). Standards have relaxed and it's now used on TV, but "boobs" is still considered less crude.

Comment: 'Boobs' is definitely considered less crude than 'tits' in Britain - see for instance, the name for [this item of clothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boob_tube)